# Mutator makes program run indefinitely

Tags: c#

```
using System;

class mainProgram
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Champions Mundo = new Champions("Mundo", 8000, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(Mundo);   

        //using mutator makes my program run forever at this point
        Mundo.Health = 10000;
        Console.WriteLine(Mundo.Health);

    }

}


class Champions
{
    private string name;
    private int health;
    private int mana;

    public Champions(string name, int health, int mana)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.health = health;
        this.mana = mana;
    }

    public Champions()
    {
    }

    public int Health
    {
        get
        {
           return this.health;
        }
        set
        {
            this.Health = value;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Champion: {0} Health: {1} Mana: {2}",
                            this.name, this.health, this.mana); 
    }


 }
```

Hi everyone,

Whenever I utilise the mutator method in my Main my program will run indefinitely.  What causes this problem? Is it because I have already set the value of health when I instantiated the object?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can't possibly tell from just what you've posted. Please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I'm suprised you even got it to compile with a property outside of class like that :P

was the `this.Health` recursive calling the issue or was that a typo in this example posting?

Comment: Sorry I did not include the full code. I'm still new to stack overflow and it kept on telling I could not post because there was too much code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the setter method inside of the setter. You should get a `StackOverFlowException` for that, try setting the backing field instead of the property itself:

```
public int Health
{
    get
    {
        return this.health;
    }
    set
    {
        this.health = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Health` property sets itself recursively, so it will just repeat indefinitely until a `StackOverflowException`.  You need to set `this.health` not `this.Health`.

You should also use auto-implemented properties in a case like this, to avoid boilerplate code. So instead of

```
private int health;
public int Health
{
    get { return health; }
    set { health = value; }
}
```

you can instead use

```
public int Health { get; set; }
```

which will define a hidden private backing field automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, calling `this.Health = value;` in the setter will call the setter again (and again and again and again) - I'd imaging it will eventually get a stack overflow and die...